# troubleshoot needed for LaTeX Error: Command \item invalid in math mode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, errors, itemize

Can someone please troubleshoot this?

It gives me an

> `\item` invalid in math mode

although I use a very similar casing on a previous frame.

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=20]
Requiring the partition function to be modular invariant, gives some properties to $\epsilon(\alpha,\beta)$.
\begin{itemize}
\item Under $\tau \rightarrow \tau+1$ 
$$
\{\alpha,\beta\} \rightarrow e^{-i\pi n(\alpha)/8}\{\alpha,\bar \alpha \beta\}.
$$
This will require $\epsilon(\alpha,\beta)=\varepsilon_\alpha\epsilon(\alpha,\bar \alpha \beta\)$.
\item Under $\tau \rightarrow -\frac{1}{\tau}$ 
$$
\{\alpha,\beta\} \rightarrow e^{i\pi n(\alpha \cap \beta)/4}\{\beta, \alpha\}.
$$
This will require $\epsilon(\alpha,\beta)=\delta_\alpha\delta_\beta\epsilon(\beta, \alpha)\varepsilon_{\alpha \cap \beta}^{-2}$.
\end{itemize}
In the equations above $\varepsilon_\alpha=e^{-i\pi n(\alpha)/8}$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this Beamer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You have `\beta\)$` that should be `\beta)$`.

Comment: Also, a tip: use `\[` ... `\]` instead of `$$` ... `$$`. See [Why is \\[ … \\] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typing error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spurious `\)` before the start of the second `\item`, which should only be `)`.